# What should the type annotation for a python property setter's argument be?

Tags: python, types, properties, getter-setter

Does python have a stance on the [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) type annotation for a property setter's argument? I see two options, both of which seem valid (according to me, and to mypy).

Consider:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any

@dataclass
class Foo:
    _bar: int = 1

    @property
    def bar(self) -> int:
        return self._bar

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, value) -> None:
        self._bar = value
```

The question is:

> Should `@bar.setter`'s `value` argument be typed with `typing.Any` or with `int`?

On one hand, within the setter, having the expected type *hint* would be nice for performing validations, but on the other hand, the incoming value could be of any type.

One thing of note, though; mypy *does* warn about the incorrect assignment to a property setter:

```py
f = Foo()
f.bar = 2     # Ok
f.bar = "baz" # Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "int")
```

I believe this comes from the revealed type of `Foo.bar` being an `int`, not from the type of the `value` argument of `@bar.setter`.

I searched through the [python/cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython) and [python/typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed) projects for examples, but didn't come up with anything definitive.

I'm very experienced with modern python, and am comfortable reading cpython sources (beit in C or python itself). An answer that references a PEP, or includes input from a cpython or mypy maintainer would be ideal.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking... annotating with  `Any`  is always *valid*. But `Any` basically just means "don't type check".

Comment: "but on the other hand, the incoming value could be of any type." What do you mean by this. suppose I have `def foo(x: int): return x`, well, the incoming value *could* be aof any type, but I am annotating that it *must* be `int`.

Comment: Just looking for best practice, which I guess could mean I'm looking for examples of type annotations for setter arguments from other languages too. Thinking about it more, I think I'm conflating the purpose of type hints with validation. In my more complicated example that spurred this question, the setter function is doing runtime type checking.. And like any other type hint, the hint should be what "I want you to call me with".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question lends itself very well to being strongly opinion based, however, I think there may be a stronger argument for mutators annotated with the expected type (ie `def bar(self, value: int) -> None:`). First, annotations were implemented to aid in static analysis rather than prviding any real runtime benefit (they currently do not to my knowledge. From [PEP 484 rationale](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#rationale-and-goals):

> Of these goals, static analysis is the most important. This includes support for off-line type checkers such as mypy, as well as providing a standard notation that can be used by IDEs for code completion and refactoring.

If type annotations are largely meant to benefit in static analysis, linting, etc it would make sense that you would want to be able to check that you are passing in the wrong type rather than potentially discover at runtime that you have not handled the parameter properly with type checks using `isinstance` for example.

This would also mean that we can do more with less, since the more specific `int` annotation would remove the need for us to add those type guards:

```py
def bigger_fun(n: Any) -> None:
    if isinstance(n, float):
        # do something...
    else
        # dosomething else...

def smaller_fun(n: int) -> None:
    # do something
```

You will know exactly what type you will receive and how to handle it, rather than needing to implement different multiple conditional branches to first cast the parameter to an expected value before operating on it. This will allow allow you to make your mutators as slim as possible with only minimal internal logic / processing.

If you were to pass it the wrong type, your IDE or static analysis tool will at the very least warn you when passing a `float` for `smaller_fun` for example. On the other hand, using `Any` might produce unexpected behavior for some types, which introduces runtime bugs which could be difficult to track down.

Now more specifically to your question, the same PEP touches upon the use of `@property` annotations in [The Meaning of Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-meaning-of-annotations)

> Type checkers are expected to attempt to infer as much information as necessary. The minimum requirement is to handle the builtin decorators @property, @staticmethod and @classmethod.

This means that you can expect the `@property` annotation should function normally as you'd expect. Without any special treatment.

While python is at heart a dynamically typed language, methods like a mutator are very strongly tied to a specific value (and therfore type) and should only really do one thing rather than one of many things. So while it probably makes since for a comparison method like `__gt__`, which will likely perform different operations for different types,  to take an `Any` value, a mutator should take as narrow a scope as possible.

Finally, even though type hints are not and probably should never be mandatory, all of the most popular python IDEs such as Pycharm automatically support type hints. They will often give warnings even when another programmer may not be annotating types, but the type can be safely inferred. This means that even when using a library with types hints, mutators with an `int` annotation, will still be more informative and useful to the end-user than an `Any` annotation.